# How to Drag an Image Displayed in a StaticBitmap in a wxPython Frame

Tags: python, wxpython

I have been trying to find a way to drag an image in a frame but all the search results are about drag-AND-drop functionality.

I have experimented with it. I can recreate the image over and over again with the coordinates obtained from the event object while dragging but this gets messy as the window gets clattered with a LOT of images.

```
  def OnDrag(self, event):
    if event.Dragging():
      self.dragging = True

      if not self.drag_pos:
        self.drag_pos = event.GetPosition()
      else:
        pos = event.GetPosition()
        if self.drag_pos[0] > pos[0]:
          if self.drag_pos[-1] > pos[-1]:
            displacement = (10, 10)
          else:
            displacement = (10, -10)
        else:
          if self.drag_pos[-1] > pos[-1]:
            displacement = (-10, 10)
          else:
            displacement = (-10, -10)

        self.page_pos = (self.page.GetPosition() - displacement)
        # self.page.Destroy() # Here causes Segmentation Fault: 11
        self.page = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, self.img.ConvertToBitmap(), size=(self.width, self.height), pos=self.page_pos)
```

Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/ShalaQweghen/98f00a67b2dd76593dfd8d568aa68698).

If I have tried to call `.Destroy` on the StaticBitmap in OnDrag event handler, it causes a segmentation fault.

I have tried to call `.SetPosition` on the StaticBitmap but it didn't do anything.

I have also tried to `.Refresh` the StaticBitmap after `.SetPosition` but it stops the dragging event.

I have tried `wx.DragImage` and `wx.CallLater` but to no avail.

I would appreciate any help in this issue.

**EDIT:**

I couldn't solve it however I tried. So I placed the bitmaps as the background of the frame instead of placing them in a `StaticBitmap`. It solved my main issue. Of course, it needs some refining. Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/ShalaQweghen/044f03ba2761ddab82f3eabe82485b15) in case anybody trying to solve a similar issue needs an example.

Comment: There is an example in the wxPython demo called DragImage that shows how to do this: https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/demo/DragImage.py. It looks like the main thing to do that you haven't done is basically redo the background in the `OnEraseBackground` method.

Comment: Thank you @MikeDriscoll. I checked the link and tried to implement `OnEraseBackground`. But I couldn't get a hang of it. So, I decided to set bitmaps as the background of the frame instead of placing them inside a `StaticBitmap`. It solved my problem. Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/ShalaQweghen/044f03ba2761ddab82f3eabe82485b15) if interested.

Comment: I figured it had to be something like that, but I don't have a lot of experience with drawing in wxPython